# Good Practice: Continually create threads or reuse threads

Tags: android, c++, linux, windows, multithreading

I am developing a cross-platform (Windows, Linux and Android) C++ application which needs to dispatch workload. This workload needs to be dispatched on a separate thread and the possibility exists for Asynchronous submission of multiple workloads. The application runs on a thread, not the main thread, which executes a script. This script in turn will execute the workload submissions on additional threads. Time is not critical in this application as the workload is running on a hardware emulator.

If the application was time critical I would pre-create a thread pool and dispatch the submissions on threads cyclically, threads which never exit... however as the tool is not time critical and never will be, I am considering creating new threads and letting them expire on each submission purely for simplicity and schedule.

I am trying to determine if this is considered good practice? I am also trying to determine the  implications for each OS: E.G. This may be Okay on Windows but may cause a problem on Android version 4.2 that I am unaware of.

If I should not continually create new threads on each dispatch, then I am looking for solid reasons why this should not be done. Thanks for you input. P.S. I was not able to find this answered in a search.

Comment: So basically you are asking if it is ok to be a bit lazy in a pgm where your laziness doesn't much matter in order to expedite your schedule?  That's not a *good* practice but I'll bet it is a widely accepted and practiced one.  The primary reason for thread pools is efficiency.  If you don't care about it or it isn't cost effective enough to care about it then it is what it is.  A thing worth worrying about here is (without a pool) is limiting the number of threads you start spawning, which becomes counter productive at a point.

Comment: Cheers for the response. You are partially correct that its to expedite a schedule and not doing out of laziness is bad practice. Its not laziness though (else I would have just done it and not posted on SO). I believe its a real consideration: Do we need the extra work/time to implement thread queues if they are absolutely never used to the full. + for pointing out that laziness is not good practice.

Comment: At least in a reasonably well designed API, using a thread pool isn't any more (and often less) work than creating the threads directly. As such, I'm hard put to think of a circumstance under which it seems like this would make much (if any) sense.

Comment: Understood. I'll probably implement a thread pool just because of the almost indignation (but not quite) the idea of not using one receives. Just to clarify though, the application is not a service/daemon which runs continually dispatching workload, rather its a tool which will fire off one shot test scripts, which will fire off a bunch of threads and exit afterwards. I guess it's because the application is "one-shot and exit", which is raising this question for me. I would not have even asked for a service. Cheers.

Comment: There is a little known pattern called the _Back-Off pattern_. Here you do some processing on the thread, then `Sleep()` for 1 sec, if there is more work then process it and `Sleep()` another 1 sec. However, if there is no work then you 2x the previous `Sleep()` time, so now you `Sleep()` for 2 sec. If there is still no more work then you `Sleep()` for 4 sec asf. I use this pattern on a web server message queue as it's not always messages to be processed. You usually have a cap too, on my web server the cap is 1 minute so that a user will never have to wait longer than 1 minute for a message.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen - whay would one use a back-off loop instead of a condvar or semaphore to signal the availablity of new work?

Comment: @MartinJames I think the option with the least number of concurrency issues is a `std::atomic<unsigned int> numJobs` , then just iterate it `numJobs++` to signal a new job and `numJobs--` once a job is done. Check with `if (numJobs.load() > 0) DoWork()` and and update w/o iterations using `numJobs.store(newVal)`. Even faster is  `std::atomic_flag ` which is guaranteed to be lock-free, use this if you just want to signal that there is work to be done and you don't care about the number of jobs in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating threads on-demand and letting them expire on submission might seem simple and, as other commenters have suggested, is often done.  I hardly ever do such a thing for the following reasons:

- You have to actually create the threads and terminate them correctly.
  This can be non-trivial and is error-prone - search SO for 'terminate
  a thread' posts - there are thousands.  Problems with terminating 
  threads can be avoided by not terminating them.
- Not only is creating/terminating threads much more costly in terms of the actual thread creation/termination, but any classes used by the thread/s have to be continually created/destroyed as well. This can be costly for some classes and bugs in dtors can result in an ever-increasing memory leak, (classes in opaque libraries, that you      cannot fix, have been known to leak:). This can be avoided by not  terminating the threads and so avoiding destruction of such objects.
- Creating a thread requires its stack to be allocated. Many OS
  allocate over-large default stacks that eat up virtual memory space. 
  This can be a problem with 'bursty' workloads where a sudden arrival
  of a large batch of work can result in a ridiculously large number of
  threads and memory-runaway.
- If you are in the unfortunate position of having to share some
  resources across the threads, the more threads, the more contention
  you will have on those resources, so increasing the time spent
  waiting for locks.
- An unknown number of threads makes debugging, which is already
  difficult with multithreading, even more difficult.  This is, for me,
  is an overriding consideration and I will do almost anything to avoid
  multiple create/terminate/join patterns.
- Create/terminate/join is notorious for preventing the prompt shutdown
  of apps.  If you have had any badly-designed GUI apps on your PC that
  do not immediately close when requested, (and I'm sure you have),
  join() is likely to be the reason.

  Submitting tasks to thread pools is much safer and is to be
  preferred.

  Application-lifetime threads, ie. created at app startup, are
  dedicated to some task and never terminated, are also fine and, for
  some functionality like logging, are more suited than threadpool
  tasks.

  Multiple create/terminate/join?  Just try very, very hard to avoid
  it.  Put this pattern in the 'desperation' category:)

Comment: Though I am unlikely to have to deal with burst issues in my environment, you definitely make a good point about debugging. Thread pool work is in progress. Thanks for answering the question with the details of why/why-not instead of just exasperations.